# reactive form is not able to identify username, email, course

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In a reactive form, the error is that is not able to identify username, email and course fields.

1. In ts file I created the formGroup
2. In formcontrol I ceatred 3 property username, email, course
3. In HTML file I have bind with same name in formControl

   ```
       <form [formGroup]="myReactiveForm">

           <div >
               <label>User Name</label>
               <input type="text" [formControl]="username">
           </div>


           <div >
               <label>Email</label>
               <input type="text" [formControl]="email">
           </div>


           <div>
               <select name="course" [formControl]="course">
                   <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
                   <option value="">Html</option>
               </select>
           </div>


           <button>Submit</button>
       </form>

   </div>
   ```

   ```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-comp',
     templateUrl: './comp.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./comp.component.css']
   })
   export class CompComponent implements OnInit {

     myReactiveForm : FormGroup;



     constructor() { }

         ngOnInit(): void {

           this.myReactiveForm = new FormGroup({

             'username' : new FormControl(null),
             'email' : new FormControl(null),
             'course' : new FormControl(null)
           });
         }

       }
   ```

And the error is:

```
`error TS2339: Property 'username' does not exist on type 'CompComponent'`

    8             <input type="text" [formControl]="username">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to use formControlName, like `<input type="text" formControlName="email">` because `formControl` is when you are using form controls directly, not a form group.